# dynamic dropdownlist disappear

Tags: c#, asp.net

I populate dynamically added dropdownlists from a database. When I press a button on the asp.net form the dynamically added dropdownlists repopulate. 
If I check for ispostback and block the creation code the ddls dont display. What is the best way to prevent the ddls being built each post.

```
public partial class search : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    Panel SearchPanel;
    protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Create a Dynamic Panel
        SearchPanel = new Panel();
        SearchPanel.ID = "SearchPanel";
        SearchPanel.BorderWidth = 1;
        SearchPanel.Width = 300;
        this.form1.Controls.Add(SearchPanel);

        CreateDropDownList("search1");
        CreateDropDownList("search2");

        Button btnAddDd2 = new Button();
        btnAddDd2.ID = "btnAddDd2";
        btnAddDd2.Text = "Search";
        btnAddDd2.Width = 80;
        btnAddDd2.Click += new System.EventHandler(search_click);
        this.form1.Controls.Add(btnAddDd2);

    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void CreateDropDownList(string ID)
    {
        DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
        ddl.ID = ID;
        ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem("--Select--", ""));
        ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem("One", "1"));
        ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem("Two", "2"));
        ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem("Three", "3"));
        ddl.AutoPostBack = true;

        SearchPanel.Controls.Add(ddl);

        Literal lt = new Literal();
        lt.Text = "<br />";
        SearchPanel.Controls.Add(lt);

        Thread.Sleep(2000); // simulate wait time of database load
    }

    protected void search_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // find something
    }
}
```

Comment: Every dynamically created control _must be_ recreated on _every_ postback, with the same ID as before and in `Page_Load` at the latest. You can store the number of created controls in `ViewState` or `Session`, that's all you need to create them again on postback.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically created controls lost their values when post back event is fired. Also, if you check `IsPostback` then on postback event you will loose dynamic controls. To overcome this issue you need to use `ViewState` property.

For detailed description and example on that, follow this link: [Retaining State for Dynamically Created Controls in ASP.NET applications](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3684/Retaining-State-for-Dynamically-Created-Controls-i)

Comment: Thanks for the info. Have followed the link and used the code but no controls ever get created. Does AutoEventWireup="true" need to be false in the markup?